# REST/POST: how to receive a PDF file?

Tags: json, vb.net, post, dotnet-httpclient

I have to make a web request (POST) to receive a PDF from a cloud server.

This code works, the JSON string is correct, but I get warnings (use httpclient instead of webrequest, Await missing) and the received file is not complete (I only get page 2/2). Obviously, this is not e perfect solution.

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim a As New AppBehaviour With {
            .DEALER_ALWAYS_SAVE_DHP_XML_PDF_EXPORT_BIT = 4,
            .XML_EXPORT_XML_FORMAT = "UTF8",
            .DONOT_CREATE_NEW_CLOUDID = 1,
            .XML_EXPORT_INCLUDING_MANU_CUSTNR = 1
        }
        Dim c As New Root With {
            .customerNo = "12345",
            .pass = "67890",
            .cloudId = "abcdef",
            .returnAsFile = True,
            .wawiManufacturer = "",
            .appBehaviour = a
        }
        Dim RestURL As String = "https://adresse.net"
        Dim client As New Net.Http.HttpClient
        Dim JsonData As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c)
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(RestURL)
        request.ContentType = "application/json"
        request.Method = "POST"
        Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
            streamWriter.Write(JsonData.ToString())
            streamWriter.Flush()
            streamWriter.Close()
        End Using
        Try
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Using output As Stream = File.OpenWrite("D:\test.pdf")
                Using input As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                    input.CopyTo(output)
                End Using
            End Using
            MessageBox.Show("file successfully received")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("download error, Ex: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot in advance

code is working - no errors, but the result is not correct

Comment: It's rather bizarre that you get only page two of two in a readable format.  Generally speaking, it's more expected you would get either a rubbish file or the whole thing.  Are you sure the entire files is actually being served by the api?

Comment: It is bizarre. Sometimes I get 1 page, sometimes 2 pages. I never get a corrupt file. Maybe someone could rewrite my code ?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not convinced the problem is your code (Although would recommend moving to the more future proof HTTPClient\Request\Response pattern over WebReqests) so not sure there is anything to rewrite.

Comment: Aside, this really isn't the place to come to ask for people to rewrite your code.   Especially since you've not provided any information about the cloud service so no one other than you knows what is required to consume it correctly.

Comment: I do not have much information about the API: the body, the method, the URL, the parameters - that's all. I am not aksing for a complete rewrite. I need help with the httpclient class.